# Where exists & Select 1 from - in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, where-clause, exists

I am trying to create this `MySQL` query in `SQLAlchemy`:

```
SELECT ClientID, TypeID, C, AVG_G
FROM join_table T1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM join_table T2 WHERE T2.ClientID = T1.ClientID AND T2.TypeID <> T1.TypeID
)
ORDER BY ClientID, TypeID
;
```

This is how I tried to implement:

```
T1 = aliased(Join)
T2 = aliased(Join)

return (
    session.query(T1.c.ClientID, T1.c.TypeID, T1.c.C, T1.c.AVG_G)
    .filter(T1.c.ClientID == T2.c.ClientID, T1.c.TypeID != T2.c.TypeID)
    .exists()
    .order_by(T1.c.ClientID, T1.c.TypeID)
)
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'Exists' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'order_by'
```

Following the [documentation's](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists) example I might need to take out the exists part into another `session.query` object, only I'm not sure how would this interact with the `where` part after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is better to take out the inner select Query object into a variable and call the `.exists()` function on that, so you won't have to repeat that select.

My problem was missing that SQLAlchemy maps the query structure quite intuitively and while my query had two `WHERE` clauses, my SQLAlchemy version had only one `.filter()` call.

Also the documentation hints this as well:

```
"The EXISTS construct is usually used in the WHERE clause:"

session.query(User.id).filter(q.exists()).scalar()
```

So this is the solution:

```
T1 = aliased(Join)
T2 = aliased(Join)

S = (
        session.query(T1.c.ClientID, T1.c.TypeID, T1.c.C, T1.c.AVG_G)
        .filter(T1.c.ClientID == T2.c.ClientID, T1.c.TypeID != T2.c.TypeID)
    )

return (
    session.query(T1.c.ClientID, T1.c.TypeID, T1.c.C, T1.c.AVG_G)
    .filter(S.exists())
    .order_by(T1.c.ClientID, T1.c.TypeID)
)
```

And if you set `echo=true` in your engine, you can check that this indeed translates into:

```
SELECT anon_1.`ClientID`, anon_1.`TypeID`, anon_1.`C`, anon_1.`AVG_G`
FROM Join AS anon_1
WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM Join AS anon_2 WHERE anon_1.`ClientID` = anon_2.`ClientID` AND anon_1.`TypeID` != anon_2.`TypeID`) 
ORDER BY anon_1.`ClientID`, anon_1.`TypeID`
```